C/C++ API to list enabled gnome extensions
There is a command gnome-extensions list --enabled to list enabled extensions. Is there any C/C++ API to check the same from code?

What does this have to do with Ubuntu OS?

@David This seems to me as a perfectly asked question here, as it has to do with GNOME. However, it may fit better in https://stackoverflow.com/ I don't have an exact idea about what the answer would be, but I have a feeling that may be related to GDBus library.

@FedKad As this question lacks any reference to Ubuntu my comment is a valid one.

You could look to see how it is implemented in the gnome-extensions tool itself - I'm guessing a bit, but it looks like the relevant source code file is command-list.c

Your question is getting flagged to be closed because it does not provide enough detail as it does not reference a specific Ubuuntu version, why this is relevant to Ubuntu.  Stack Overflow would be a much better place for this question.
